# Python discord bot cog slash command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need help with this code. I tried another command without options and it worked well but for this command i need option and im not really sure how to do it. Here is what i have done but i think theres lot of mistakes with options.

```
import discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from app_commands import options

timestamp = datetime.now()

embed1 = discord.Embed(title="ERROR",
  description="Please provide a valid number greater than 0",
  colour=0xf50000,
  timestamp=datetime.now())

embed = discord.Embed(title="SUCCESFULLY",
  description="Successfully deleted!",
  colour=0x2b2d31,
  timestamp=datetime.now())

class Purge(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="Purge", description="Purge messages")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def purge(self, ctx, amount: Option(str)):
        if {amount} <= 0:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
            return

        try:
            deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit={amount}+1)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await ctx.send("I don't have permission to delete messages.")
        except discord.HTTPException:
            await ctx.send("An error occurred while deleting messages.")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Purge(bot))
```

Tried to get option to slash command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code. You should take a look at other people's code, learn from it, and read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

### 1. Getting user input

In your case, you don't need to set specific options. Conventionally, purge commands only require an `int` input for the amount to purge. You can do this by simply type annotating the `amount` parameter to `int`.

```
@app_commands.command()
async def purge(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
    ...
```

Additionally, you can also set a range. Say you want the amount to be positive (above zero), you can use [app_commands.Range](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Range) for this.

```
@app_commands.command()
async def purge(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: app_commands.Range[int, 1]):
    ...
```

This would only accept amounts 1 or more, with no maximum.

### 2. Permission Check

Slash commands use a different permissions check from normal prefix commands. Your code as is, will not check the permissions correctly and anyone will be able to run the command. For this, use [app_commands.checks.has_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions).

```
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int):
    ...
```

### 3. Misconception of ctx

Conventionally, `ctx` is a variable name we use to represent [commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context). Slash commands, however, use [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction).

Here is a simple code example of a slash command.

```
@app_commands.command(name="mycommand") #  Assuming this is in a cog
async def mycommand_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello World")
```

When you run a slash command, it has to be responded to. We do this using [interaction.response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.response). Otherwise, the interaction will fail.

Make sure to look up code examples and look at the documentation for reference.

For further details on [Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction), [app_commands.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#command), [Interaction.response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interactionresponse).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find info from docs but i didnt found. Im very sure this will help a lot!